# PIR sensor (HC-SR501) with n-Mosfet transistor not switching off

Tags: mosfet, sensor, pir

I have none to less electronics background, with limited knowledge whatsoever. I've used some schematics from the internet https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugDPdgGekNo to put in place the below setup :
[image]

A PIR sensor (HC-SR501) + n-Mosfet transistor irfz24n + 9v battery to power on a 9v led light bulb.

The problem is that with this setup, the led light bulb doesn't turn off when no motion is detected, it remains opened.
I have measured aside the PIR sensor outputs: it's 3.6V when some motion is detected and when no motion is detected it drops to 0v.

Any advice on what is wrong is appreciated.

Comment: Please include a schematic.

Comment: Your Imgur image is pretty, but, PLEASE, draw a schematic.

Comment: "it remains opened" - what does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct pin-out for the MOSFET you are using (superimposed on to your incorrect pin-out): -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misinterpreting your image (and you really should use the schematic editor), you have connected the gate to ground and the source to the output. This will not work. What you want is

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0pqkI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>